# using st_mode to identify file or directory

Tags: python, paramiko, stat

is there any way to identify whether an object is file or directory using st_mode value?
I'm using paramiko lstat() to retrieve the st_mode information from sftp files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the [stat structure](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) `st_mode` does contain that information.

Use the [`stat` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html) to determine if it is a directory:

```
import stat

if stat.S_ISDIR(lstat_result.st_mode):
```

Comment: Yes Thanks..:) it worked with a small correction:

    import stat

    if stat.S_ISDIR(lstat_result.st_mode):