# How to check a remote path is a file or a directory?

Tags: python, file, directory, paramiko

I am using `SFTPClient` to download files from the remote server. However, I don't know if the remote path is a file or a directory. If the remote path is a directory, I need to handle this directory recursively.

This is my code:

```py
def downLoadFile(sftp, remotePath, localPath):
    for file in sftp.listdir(remotePath):  
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(remotePath, file)): # file, just get
            try:
                sftp.get(file, os.path.join(localPath, file))
            except:
                pass
        elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(remotePath, file)): # dir, need to handle recursive
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(localPath, file))
            downLoadFile(sftp, os.path.join(remotePath, file), os.path.join(localPath, file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    paramiko.util.log_to_file('demo_sftp.log')
    t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    t.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
```

I found the problem:
The function `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.isdir` returns `False`. So, it looks like these functions can not work for remotePath.

Comment: check extension of path if there is extension or .

Comment: Files don't necessarily have an extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using st\_mode to identify file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861967/using-st-mode-to-identify-file-or-directory)

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: @thefourtheye i just want to download a directory using `SFTPClient`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The file is on romote server, i can check the st_mode in local server?

Comment: @BlackMamba: You use the `lstat()` function to retrieve the stat info from the server.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.isdir()` only work on **local** filenames.

I'd use the `sftp.listdir_attr()` function instead and load full `SFTPAttributes` objects, and inspect their `st_mode` attribute with the `stat` module utility functions:

```
import stat

def downLoadFile(sftp, remotePath, localPath):
    for fileattr in sftp.listdir_attr(remotePath):  
        if stat.S_ISDIR(fileattr.st_mode):
            sftp.get(fileattr.filename, os.path.join(localPath, fileattr.filename))
```

Answer (score 6):

Below steps to be followed to verify if remote path is FILE or DIRECTORY:

1) Create connection with remote

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname,port))
transport.connect(username = user, password = pass)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

2) Suppose you have directory "/root/testing/" and you would like to check through ur code.Import stat package

```
import stat
```

3) Use below logic to check if its file or Directory

```
fileattr = sftp.lstat('root/testing')
if stat.S_ISDIR(fileattr.st_mode):
    print 'is Directory'
if stat.S_ISREG(fileattr.st_mode):
    print 'is File'
```

Answer (score 4):

use module [`stat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html)

```
import stat

for file in sftp.listdir(remotePath):  
    if stat.S_ISREG(sftp.stat(os.path.join(remotePath, file)).st_mode): 
        try:
            sftp.get(file, os.path.join(localPath, file))
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution? It is not proper one but one of possible if you need to combine with listing directory.

```
    is_directory = False

    try:
        sftp.listdir(path)
        is_directory = True
    except IOError:
        pass

    return is_directory
```